# How to escape non standard characters to windows 1252 character set

Tags: xml, xslt, character-encoding

I have xml file that has non standard characters and I would like to transform those to windows 1252 encoding like so &#nnn I don't understand XSLT well but I have tried this any help please here is the XML and the XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="Windows-1252"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Recordset">
    <Recordset><xsl:apply-templates /></Recordset>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

XML example for characters

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Recordset> 
128 € euro sign
129    NOT USED
130 ‚ single low-9 quotation mark
131 ƒ Latin small letter f with hook
132 „ double low-9 quotation mark
133 … horizontal ellipsis
134 † dagger
135 ‡ double dagger
136 ˆ modifier letter circumflex accent
137 ‰ per mille sign
138 Š Latin capital letter S with caron
139 ‹ single left-pointing angle quotation mark
140 Œ Latin capital ligature OE
141    NOT USED
142 Ž Latin capital letter Z with caron
143    NOT USED
144    NOT USED
145 ‘ left single quotation mark
146 ’ right single quotation mark
147 “ left double quotation mark
148 ” right double quotation mark
149 • bullet
150 – en dash
151 — em dash
152 ˜ small tilde
153 ™ trade mark sign
154 š Latin small letter s with caron
155 › single right-pointing angle quotation mark
156 œ Latin small ligature oe
157    NOT USED
158 ž Latin small letter z with caron
159 Ÿ Latin capital letter Y with diaeresis
160 no-break space 
</Recordset>
```

Comment: XML supports the Unicode standard so any Unicode character is standard character in XML. Whether you use XML with XSLT or otherwise, parsing of an XML input document like you have shown is no problem as long as the XML document correctly declares its encoding in the XML declaration at the beginning. Your example with `<?xml version="1.0"?>` however does not do that.  So that begs the question? What is the encoding of the XML input document?

Comment: @MartinHonnen     utf-8 is the XML input

Comment: The notation &#123; in XML always represents a character whose Unicode codepoint is 123, never a character whose encoding is 123 in something like Windows-1252 codepage. That's true regardless of the encoding of the XML file.

Comment: @MichaelKay the above is an xml on window 1252 character sets if that was to be transformed correctly the symbols will be represented by `&#nnn `which is the windows encoding all I am trying to do is have an xslt like the above which can recognise that and append the correct representation. The nnn notation will be the numbers at the begin eg bullet point  `&#149`

Comment: @Tim, no, you missed my point. In XML `&#149;` represents the control character "message waiting" (and is allowed only in XML 1.1), regardless of the encoding of the file.  Bullet point is `&#8226;`, again, regardless of the file's encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters you are asking about are representable in the document character encoding you are asking about. So, you don't need to use numeric character entity references.

XSLT seems like overkill to change the document character encoding. You need to read the original XML file and write it out again with a different document character encoding. That would cause Unicode codepoints that can't be represented in your chosen character encoding to be serialized as numeric character entity references. No XSLT need be involved and you would have to all that for XSLT. So, you could skip the XSLT step.

Nonetheless, if you do have a tool that reads an XML file, applies a transform and writes it out again, respecting the xsl:output encoding attribute, then you can use the *Identity Transform* with an appropriate output element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="XML" encoding="Windows-1252" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you do that on your sample document, you'll see "128 € euro sign" is indeed encoded in Windows-1252.

```
31 32 38 20 80 20 65 75 72 6F 20 73 69 67
```

If you want € represented as a numeric character entity reference, encode with a document character encoding for a character set that doesn't support it, such as IBM437.

It's unclear why you want a document character encoding other than UTF-8, though. An XML processor can't get very far if it doesn't support the character set for XML, which is Unicode.